# Утилита touch, генерация имен файлов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Нужно создать файлы в каталоге с именами от `aa` до `zz`, тоесть `aa,ab,ac...zy,zz`.

Как это можно прописать в терминале? Возможно ли обойтись без цикла? Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На `bash` можно просто:

```
touch {a..z}{a..z}
```

Comment: спасибо,только как это понять {a..z}{a..z}?

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich, посмотрите [здесь](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace#ranges)